# .NET inheritance: suppress a property from the base class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

Consider the Employee, Manager, and Assistant classes:

```
public class Emp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Manager Manager { get; set; }
    public Assistant Assistant { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Emp
{ 
}

public class Assistant : Emp
{
}
```

The goal is to DISALLOW a piece of code to access a property like this:

```
var foo = new Manager();
var elmo = new Emp();
elmo.Manager = foo;
elmo.Manager.Manager = new Manager(); 
//how to disallow access to Manager.Manager ?
```

Because `Manager` inherits from `Emp`, it has a `.Manager` and `.Assistant` property.

**Question**

Are there any modifiers in .NET's inheritance implementation to remove the `.Manager` and `.Assistant` properties?

**Update**

Thank you for your great answers, everyone. I was hoping the simplification and contrivance of Emp/Mgr would show through in this question. It's clear that the inheritance, in this example, should be taken to another commonality (something like `Person`, where the classes would share names, birthdates, etc.) Your input is much appreciated!

Comment: Smells like a design issue to me. While Managers may report to another manager, Assistants probably don't have an assistant. Perhaps the base should be Person...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing this would violate the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and is usually a sign of a questionable design.  In general, any subclass should be able to be used in any context that a base class would be.  If `Manager`s don't have `.Manager`s, then they aren't `Emp`s, and shouldn't inherit from them.

Answer (score 5):

No - because it would break [Liskov's Subsitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Basically, you can add things, but you can't take them away.

You could potentially override the property to throw an exception at execution time, but you can't do it at compile time.

Generally if you want to disallow this sort of thing, you should consider composition rather than inheritance, as you don't have a genuine inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

You can make the base class property `virtual`, then override it to throw an exception in the setter, but there's no way to give a compile-time error.  After all, there is nothing you do at compile time to prevent

```
(elmo.Manager as Employee).Manager = new Manager();
```

However, you can write

```
public class ManagerEmployee : Emp {     
    public new ManagerEmployee Manager { 
        get { return base.Manager; }
    }
}
```

Note that this won't prevent casting.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things, it depends. Given the following classes:

```
public class foo
{
    public string Test { get { return "foo"; } } 
}

public class bar : foo
{
    public new string Test { get { return "bar"; } }
}
```

And the following code:

```
        bar a = new bar();
        // returns bar
        literalTest1.Text = a.Test;

        foo b = new foo();
        // returns "foo"
        literalTest2.Text = b.Test;

        foo c = new bar();
        // returns "foo"
        literalTest3.Text = c.Test;
```

You can see, based on the comments above, that you *can* override a property that is not declared as virtual. However, the overridden property will only be used when the object variable is declared as the type that overrides the property - not as any of its ancestors. This effectively breaks polymorphism.

Fix your ancestor class instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said. No. I'll add that if not every employee has a manager and an assistant, then your inheritance hierarchy is wrong. It would seem that the only thing an employee and manager share is a name. You can add via inheritance, but you cannot take away via inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this, and you wouldn't want to - either Manager is an Employee and has a Manager and an Assistant, or it doesn't and hence should have a different base class i.e. this situation indicates a design flaw. One possibility could be to return null for these properties though if that makes sense for the domain.